# Java printing double value zero in printf

Tags: java, double, printf, string-formatting

I have in my function the following statement `System.out.printf("The balance is %0.1f", acct.getBalance());`, sometimes the balance will be 0, when this is the case, I get `MissingFormatWidthException`, how can I make this work even for `0.0`? It works perfectly for doubles greater than 0.0.

Comment: `getBalance() + 0.0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
System.out.printf("The balance is %.1f",(double)acct.getBalance());
```

OR

```
System.out.printf("The balance is %1.1f",(double)acct.getBalance());
```

`%0.1f` interprets as print as a floating point at least 0 wide and a precision of 2. It should ideally give errors.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
 NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
 f.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
 double d = 0.0;
 System.out.println(f.format(d));
```

Output:

```
 $0.00
```

Comment: This works too, however, I prefer to to do it using printf without the need to create extra objects

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

System.out.printf("The balance is %0.1f", acct.getBalance() !=0 ? acct.getBalance() : 0.0);